# How to stop DIR command counting "Thumbs.db"

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer, dir, thumbs.db

We have a process that executes a `DIR` on multiple folders to check that the correct documents have been generated by another process.

In each of the target directories we use this command:

```
dir /A:-D "x:\name of document\_archive\YYYY\MONTH\dd.mm.yyyy\" /b
```

For one of the directories, we are getting an incorrect number because *Thumbs.db* is being counted.

How can I change the DIR command (which is actually being execute using **xp_cmdshell** from SQL Server) to ignore *Thumbs.db*?

or do I need to actually remove those files as explained [here by PeterNetLive](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000683.htm) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the dir command into `findstr` to filter the lines 'Thumbs.db'. The flag `/V` displays non-matching lines only, the flag `/I` makes the search case-insensitive. The full command would be:

```
dir /A:-D /B "x:\...\" | findstr /V /I "^Thumbs.db$"
```

Comment: +1 if you squint hard you can see `ls | grep -v` :-)